# Prove that: $|(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)| \le 1.$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

Problem complex number inequality:

> Given $x,y,z$ be complex numbers such that $|x|, |y|, |z| \le 1$ and $|x+y+z| \le 1.$ Prove that $$|(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)| \le 1.$$

I see it on AOPS [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t159f6h3124919_complex_inequality).

Here is my attempt:

Let $(m;n;p)=\left(\dfrac{x}{x+y+z}; \dfrac{y}{x+y+z}; \dfrac{z}{x+y+z}\right)$ then $|m|, |n|, |p| \le 1$ and $m+n+p=1.$ On the other hand:
$$|(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)| \le 1 \Leftrightarrow |(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)| \le 1.$$
$\bullet$ Case 1: At least one in three numbers $m,n,p$ is real. Assume it is $m.$ 
Hence, $\exists a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} : n=a+ci; p=b-ci$ and $m=1-n-p=1-a-b.$ 
Since $|m|, |n|, |p| \le 1$ then $a^2+c^2 \le 1; b^2+c^2 \le 1$ and $0 \le a+b \le 2.$  
We have: \begin{align*} |(m+n)(n+p)(p+m)| &=|1-b+ci|\cdot|1-a-ci|\cdot|a+b|\\ &=\sqrt{1-2b+b^2+c^2}\cdot\sqrt{1-2a+a^2+c^2}\cdot (a+b)\\ &\le \sqrt{2(1-b)\cdot 2(1-a)}\cdot (a+b)\\ &=2\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)}\cdot (a+b)\\ &\le (2-a-b)(a+b) \le 1.\end{align*}
$\bullet$ Case 2: All $m,n,p$ are not real numbers. I haven't proved it yet.

Comment: In [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t159f6h3124919_complex_inequality).
There is a solution use strong skill. It let two in three numbers $m,n,p$ have modun $=1$, on the other hand: $|m|=|n|=1$ anh $m+n+p=1.$ If we have this then problem becomes very easy. However, there isn't proof for that, and I haven't proved it yet, also there is no reference about it.

Comment: A transformation of the given condition that could (hopefuly ?) lead to a solution : Define the third degree polynomial with roots $x,y,z$  : $P(Z):=(Z-x)(Z-y)(Z-z) \iff P(Z)=Z^3-sZ^2+rZ-p$ (with classical notations, $s=x+y+z$ for their sum,  $r=xy+yz+zx$, $p=xyz$ for their product). Your issue can be transformed in this way  into $|P(s)| \le 1 \iff |rs-p| \le 1$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. But can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: I thought it was clear enough ; $P(s)=s^3-s^3+rs-p=rs-p$